# Highlighting the button with sender tag

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have 7 buttons on my storyboard, I have associated a tag number to each of the button. And all the buttons are hooked up to a single IBAction.

In my action method I have a switch statement like `switch ([sender tag])`
which run the appropriate action according to the tag. This is all working.
But I want to add a functionality where selected button is highlight and rest of them in normal state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create property with tags:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *tags;
```

Somewhere (for example, in viewDidLoad) initialize it with values used in storyboard:

```
tags = @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5]
```

And select buttons using this tags

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    for (int i = 0; i < tags.count; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [self.view viewWithTag:tags[i]];
        button.selected = (button.tag == sender.tag);
    }
}
```

Or you can create IBOutlets for every 7 buttons and create array for it.

```
array = @[outlet1, ..., outlet7]
```

And select buttons using outlets

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
        UIButton *button = array[i];
        button.selected = (button.tag == sender.tag);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can give you some idea:

```
- (void)setupButtons {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width / 7;
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * width, 100, width, 30)];
        [self.view addSubview:button];
        button.tag = 1000 + i;
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        if (i == 0) {
            // default first button selected
            button.selected = YES;
        }
    }
}

- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [self.view viewWithTag:(1000+i)];
        button.selected = (button.tag == sender.tag);
    }
}
```